# Different types of treeview items to be binded in one single data template

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I have an MVVM based Usercontrol. The model has two classes, one class has a list of type another class as shown in the **Model** below. The problem is **I have two define two different hierarchicaldatatemplates for my treeview which are also binded to the model which is wrong**. I would like to make only one hierarchicaldatatemplate which would only know the property in my viewmodel. In the end, what I want is simply a treeview like:

|Familyname

||Personname

||Personname

The code is quite big, so I have taken some pieces. If more info is required then please let me know:

**Model**

```
public class Family
{
private string m_Name;
public string NameOfFamily
    {
        get { return m_Name; }
        set { m_Name= value; }
    } 
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons{ get; set ; }
}

public class Person
{
private string m_Name;
public string NameOfPerson
    {
        get { return m_Name; }
        set { m_Name= value; }
    } 

}
```

In the viewmodel I received the family with their respective persons e.g.

**ViewModel**

```
Family Fam = GetFamilywithrespectivepersons;
```

**View**

```
<TreeView Name="myTreeView" Grid.Column="0" Width="Auto" Height="300" ItemsSource="{Binding Fam}">
   <TreeView.Resources>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type classes:Family}" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">                      
                        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding NameOfFamily}"></TreeViewItem>                                             
       </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
       <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type classes:Person}">                                                
                        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding NameOfPerson}"></TreeViewItem>                                                                 
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
 </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly not wrong to define a `DataTemplate` per type. But since the `Person` class has no children, this `DataTemplate` doesn't have to be hierarchical.

Also, the templates shouldn't include any `TreeViewItem` elements:

```
<TreeView Name="myTreeView" Grid.Column="0" Width="Auto" Height="300" ItemsSource="{Binding Fam}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type classes:Family}" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameOfFamily}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type classes:Person}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameOfPerson}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: ok thanks, but still the xaml that you have written, has "DataType" in which you are providing the names of the classes that are present in the Model. View should not know about the model. How can I achieve this? that the view only talks to viewmodel and can populate a treeview.

Comment: What? The view certainly knows about the object to which it binds to.

Comment: @Smallestearth, `Person` or `Family` are not models, they are viemodels of items.

Comment: Yes, Family and Person should be seen as view models rather than models.

Comment: so you guys are suggesting that the classes Person and Family should lie in the viewmodel

Comment: No, these are just stand-alone classes. You should probably read up on MVVM.

Comment: Why do you think there is a DataType attribute?

Comment: Ok, may be I am very new to all this stuff but these classes Family and Person are actually DTOs that are saved and retrieved from a database and I have some hurdles in using them directly in the View. Could you suggest a method or tutorial for this stuff.

Comment: You could use the DTO as-is or you could create view model classes that wraps the DTOs. In this case, the view models would be pretty much identical copies of the DTOs.

Comment: But please ask a new question if you have another issue. Your original question has been answered.